# jQuery: How to create spotlight effect?

Tags: jquery

What I want to achieve is a spotlight effect. Dim the background, and on mouseover, lighten up the element it's hovering on.

I managed to dim the page, however, when I mouse over any element on the page, the entire thing gets covered by white.

css

```
.overlay {
position:fixed;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
background-color:#000;
opacity:0.8;
display:block;
z-index:1001;
}

.overlay-message{
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #000;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:1002;
}
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $('body *').not("div.overlay").mouseover(function (e) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        $(this).addClass('overlay-message');
                    });

                    $('body *').not("div.overlay").mouseout(function (e) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        $(this).removeClass('overlay-message');
                    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3RWXB/4/

Comment: Your demo doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why don't you simply use CSS `:hover`? You could even use CSS3 animations on it if you need a fade-in/-out effect.

Comment: My first thought would be that you have the opacity of the "spotlight" set to 1. Wouldn't that be a solid white area that would not allow you to view the contents under it?

Comment: @nietonfir it doesn't work still http://jsfiddle.net/3RWXB/6/

Comment: @AxGryndr still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlay covers all the other elements (which is what an overlay is supposed to do). That does two things that prevent this from working:

1. The mouse events never fire for the elements since they are covered by the overlay.
2. Adding the "overlay-message" class to an element doesn't change the fact that it is covered by the overlay.

How about ditching the overlay and having the following CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:#ddd;    
}
body * {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
body *:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9TQh5/3/)

Comment: this is good but right now this simply selects element and all it's parents. http://jsfiddle.net/9TQh5/5/, is it possible to make it focus on the specific element that the mouse is hovering on?

Comment: @KJW - Do you want it to look like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9A9CX/1/)? That works with text because I switched from using `opacity` to using `color`. Opacity is trickier because it is cumulative.

Comment: yes that is what I'm aiming for. except now I see that when I mouse over the parent div element, it only highlights that div element not all the descendants.

Comment: @KJW - This might not be the most efficient way to do it, but you mean you want it to work like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9A9CX/2/)?